# Updating cocoapods leads to missing files.

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Whenever I update cocoapods to the latest version I get missing file as shown in the image below. Any help is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2vR5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this nuance happen to me before, I fixed it by committing and pushing to my github repo.

Comment: hmm I tried this and it lead to errors now... FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h file not found, FireDatabaseSwiftNamesupport.h file not found, and could not build objective-c module 'firebase'

Comment: hmm, that's strange, committing it to the repo shouldn't cause errors unless there were errors before. Maybe try checking your Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths and making sure it only has $(inherited) recursive.

Answer (score 1):

> These warnings are not build warnings, they are about your SVN
>   repository. It is correct that the directories shown no longer exist,
>   CocoaPods stores the headers in Pods/Headers/{Private,Public} now. You
>   have to update your working copy to reflect those changes.

Checkout [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3341) source for more information.